# Matlab 3-D Graphics with GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, 3d

I am trying to make three objects move at the same time using for loops. I can's figure out how to make them all run at the same time since parfor is not able to be used to graphics. Any suggestions on how to implement this would be great. This is what I have so far.

```
%phobos
    % go around mars 3.13 times
    for j = 1:3.13
        for s = 1:length(b)
            e = length(q) + 1 - s;
            shape(1) = surface (22*xSphere - a(e), 22*ySphere - b(s), 22*zSphere, 'EdgeColor', 'k'); %phobos (near)
            drawnow;
            delete(shape(1));
        end
    end

    %deimos
    %go around mars 0.79 times

    for s = 1: (0.79*length(d))
        e = length(q) + 1 - s;
        shape(1) = surface (12.6*xSphere - c(e), 12.6*ySphere - d(s), 12.6*zSphere, 'EdgeColor', 'k'); %deimos (far)
        drawnow;
        delete(shape(1));
    end        
    drawnow;       
    %make 0.95 of a rotation
    for t = 1:(length(longitude)*2/3 )
        rotation1 = makehgtform('zrotate',(longitude(t)));
        set(theMars,'matrix',rotation1);
        pause (0.0001);
    end
```

Comment: You might have to figure it out all in one `for`-loop. Have the loop count the number of steps, but have the step-size differ for each object.